# Can you prove the convergence of $ \int_0^{1/2}\frac{\sin x}{x}\frac{1}{\log\frac{1}{x}}\bigg(1+\frac{1}{N}\log\frac{1}{x}\bigg)^N\,dx $?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Can you prove the following improper integral is convergent?

> $$
> \int_0^{1/2}\frac{\sin x}{x}\frac{1}{\log\frac{1}{x}}\bigg(1+\frac{1}{N}\log\frac{1}{x}\bigg)^N\,dx.
> $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. As $x \to 0^+$, one has
$$
\frac{\sin x}{x}\frac{1}{\log\frac{1}{x}}\bigg(1+\frac{1}{N}\log\frac{1}{x}\bigg)^N \sim \frac1{N^N}\cdot(-\log x)^{N-1}
$$
and the given integral is *convergent*. One may recall that, for $0<\varepsilon<1/2$, we have
$$
\int_0^{\large\varepsilon} (-\log x)^{N-1}dx=\int_{\large -\log \varepsilon}^\infty t^{N-1}e^{-t}dt<\infty
$$ for all values of $N$.

Comment: thanks for teh answer but I made a stupid mistake when writing the question. I am interested in the behaviour around $x=0$. I edited the question.

Comment: funnily enough i thought exactly about this before asking the question. The thing is that I am shamefully rusty on my analysis and I wanted somebody to rigor up my thoughts ;)

Comment: @Anarchist Birds Worship Fungus glad if you come back to analysis! ;)